# Unity Playables graph locking animated properties with values at the last frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I've been trying to use a mixture of Unity's Animators and Playables in my game, and for the most part it works well, but there's two issues that I've been having for a long time, and I've at best worked around them. Today I bashed my head against them again, and after finding no solution online I decided to get my lazy ass to finally ask for help.

The basic setup is that my characters have:

- An Animator with its controller, state machine, etc. that is used mostly for movement, jumping, climbing, etc. In case this is relevant, each character has an override controller of a generic one.
- A very simple playable graph with just an output (wrapping the animator) and an input (wrapping the specific clip I want to play at the time). This is used for actions and attacks.

The problems I have are:

1- I can't seem to figure out an elegant, clean way to know when the clip fed to the graph (second part above) is finished. Currently I circumvent this by simply calculating how long the clip is and dividing by the current animation speed factor; I also have to account for when the animation is paused (e.g. hitstop). This gets the job done but is quite unelegant, and I'm sure there must be a better way.

2- Most importantly, when I'm done with the graph and standalone animation, the values of all of the properties the clip touches become locked at their last value. They stay locked even during any animation played by the regular animator; even if any of these later animations change its value, it snaps back to that locked "last frame" value when they end.

I've tried several things to solve this:

2.1- Set the default / desired value of the properties in the idle / default animation (to "mark" them as animatable properties in the normal animator's animation). This only fixes the issue for whatever animation is touched; any other animation played after that instantly reverts to the value locked by the last frame of the animation played by the graph.

2.2- Destroy the playable wrapping the animation (I do this anyway for cleanup since I need to recreate it each time a new animation plays).

2.3- Destroy the graph and recreate it each time (surprisingly, even this keeps the values locked).

2.4- Disabling the animator and enabling it again.

I'm frankly starting to lose my mind with the second problem, so any help would be exceedingly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is pretty old, I'm adding answer (along with my related follow up question) just in case there's more people that end up here from a search engine.

1. Animations (both "legacy" and non-legacy) can fire off events at some frame - just pick point (frame on dopesheet, place in graph on curves) and click "add event"...

There's some difference on how to specify which object/script & function to call between legacy and non-legacy - but in both cases it's basically a callback so you can know for sure when some animation started/finished (or any point in between).

2. Instead of trying to change values of those properties that are "locked by animations" from `void Update()` you seem to need to do those from within `void LateUpdate()`.

From my testing - using/doing "legacy" animations (that also means "animation" component instead of "animator controller") allows you to use `Update()` - at least once the animation is finished.

And also worth keeping in mind that "animator controller" (component) doesn't accept importing "legacy" animations for any of it's states.

And animation (component) doesn't seem to play (at least not auto-play) non-legacy animations.

As of my question, well it's basically same as OPs question - is it possible to somehow "unlock" these properties (obviously without any states/animations playing) while using "newer" animator controller?

Although - based on things I've read while trying to find what's going on. Those "legacy" animations are not really "legacy" - and seem to be there to stay for reasons like being better for performance.